# How to define the Window Class Name for a C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I saw some threads on this subject, but they are too old, and I wonder if there's something new in .NET 4.5 that allows me to define the Window Class Name for a C# Windows Form. Does anyone know of something new, or has a creative idea? Many thanks.

Clarifying my question, as asked for:

The Window Class Name I'm referring to, is not the window title. It is the class name every window has, and is registered in the OS, so it can identify it and distinguish of other windows. See the Win32 API FindWindow() / RegisterWindow() / WndClass structure for deeper understanding.

The older threads say it's not possible, but they are **old**.

I hope this helps.

I'd like to add the links to the old posts, maybe they are interesting to someone:

[[Registering a custom win32 window class from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128561/registering-a-custom-win32-window-class-from-c-sharp])

[[c# - Bypassing Windows Forms ClassName name creation to one of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351148/c-sharp-bypassing-windows-forms-classname-name-creation-to-one-of-my-own])

Comment: Do you mean in the title bar of the application or the actual naming of the window class itself. The default is Form1 but you should be able to change this easily before you create the form.

Comment: I've just edit my OP to clarify it.

Comment: I never had to meddle with inner wrappings of WinApi calls used by WinForms, so I'll hardly be of any help, but I'd like to point out that WinForms barely changed from .NET 2.0 (and mostly the same goes for the WinApi as well), so I personally doubt that there is any new and easy ways to handle your problem. Also, WinForms, as any other wrapper library, is designed to hide inner complexities of underlying technology, so leveraging this hidden framework isn't an easy task.

Comment: Thanks. But I think they could have added some virtual method in the Application class to let the user define the Window Class Name as necessary. I understand it is just a matter of design decision.

Comment: Maybe WinForms was changed from old .NET versions, but WinAPI is the same. Winormms is just WinAPI wrapper. You cannot change the class name without rewriting the whole window functionality in WinAPI, so the answer is no.

Comment: And are you sure that you really need it? What is the goal? To use `SendMessage` and other APIs on your own window? Or what?

Comment: I need it for easily automating any C# WIndows Form.

Comment: I just found this **very old** MSDN post: Automating Windows Forms http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996405.aspx I'm gonna try this approach and see what I get.

Comment: @zyq Winforms existed from .NET 1.0 (year 2001) and hasn't changed much, so a lot of articles could be considered pretty old. If you can create a succinct answer from that article, then do it and post as an answer regarding the automation of winforms - it will save future visitors with the same problem a lot of time.

Comment: Can you please give us an example of what you mean by automating winforms, there might be other solutions to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: See Automating Windows Forms (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996405.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it's impossible to change the Window Class Name for a C# Windows Form, because the C# implementation defines it inside the method '`private string GetFullClassName(string className)`' and does not give a programmer any way to override the value defined inside this method.