# CreateWindowEx and RegisterClass C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a new class and then show a window with the specefied class.
I wrote following codes for that :

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UpdateWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CreateWindowEx")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(
           int dwExStyle,
           string lpClassName,
           string lpWindowName,
           int dwStyle,
           int x,
           int y,
           int nWidth,
           int nHeight,
           IntPtr hWndParent,
           IntPtr hMenu,
           IntPtr hInstance,
           IntPtr lpParam);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern System.UInt16 RegisterClassW(
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.In] ref WNDCLASSEX lpWndClass
        );
        struct WNDCLASSEX
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int cbSize;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int style;
            public IntPtr lpfnWndProc; // not WndProc
            public int cbClsExtra;
            public int cbWndExtra;
            public IntPtr hInstance;
            public IntPtr hIcon;
            public IntPtr hCursor;
            public IntPtr hbrBackground;
            public string lpszMenuName;
            public string lpszClassName;
            public IntPtr hIconSm;
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WNDCLASSEX wind_class = new WNDCLASSEX();
            wind_class.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WNDCLASSEX));
            wind_class.style = 0x00020000;
            wind_class.hbrBackground = (IntPtr) 5;
            wind_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
            wind_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
            wind_class.hInstance = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(GetType().Module);
            wind_class.hIcon = this.Icon.Handle;
            wind_class.hCursor = IntPtr.Zero;
            wind_class.lpszMenuName = string.Empty;
            wind_class.lpszClassName = "MyClass";
            wind_class.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc(IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            RegisterClassW(ref wind_class);
            IntPtr lolo = CreateWindowEx(0, "MyClass", "MyClass",0,0,0,30,40,IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero);
            ShowWindow(lolo, 1);
            UpdateWindow(lolo);
        }
    }
}
```

But it isn't working correctly.
It doesn't show the window. when i search with Spy++ by my class name , It cant find any results..

I searched in web and do some edits in my code but they didn't work.

Where is my Problem !?

Regards.

Comment: What's the reason for creating a window like this?  Doesn't the built in `NativeWindow` class already do all of this already?  Can you use that?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway : I just want to learn it :) Just it :)

Comment: First you learn to walk, then you learn to run... And you don't need to learn to go sideways... You are trying to go sideways... You don't need it. Learn to walk, learn to run, live happy.

Comment: @xanatos I don't have mood for hear advice :) If you can help me , then please do it :)

Answer (score 14):

Plain-vanilla Win32 is no fun from Win32 C, and it is much less fun from .NET. But anyway, it may be useful in rare cases. Here comes a C# class which should do what you want.
First, a general remarks on your software. In Win32, you should always check the return codes of the system calls, and in case of an error, call GetLastError() to get a more detailed information about the failure. If you had checked the result of the RegisterClass function and it failed, you would have known that it is useless to continue without having fixed that one.

The following is a class which may be used as template for further studies and which should successfully register and create a resizable window. Additionally some simple actions like doubleclick are processed in a custom Window procedure. For some parts of the code credit goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128561/registering-a-custom-win32-window-class-from-c-sharp) site being one of the very few I found in the web presenting something working.

The CreateWindowEx is tricky, because you must NOT put in a string as class name, but the result of the RegisterClassEx. The used constants are found mainly in the C-header file winuser.h. To be able to do something useful with this method, the main painting has to be done "by hand", being a cumbersome and tedious work by manipulationg Device Contexts properly. Of course, all this does not show up in the following example. The "create" method of the class may be called e.g. from a Windows Form button click. The namespace name is of course arbitrarily selected. The WinForm project is x86 32-bit, .NET 4.0.

Have fun!

```
namespace Win32FromForms
{
    delegate IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    class Win32Window
    {
        const UInt32 WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = 0xcf0000;
        const UInt32 WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        const UInt32 CS_USEDEFAULT = 0x80000000;
        const UInt32 CS_DBLCLKS = 8;
        const UInt32 CS_VREDRAW = 1;
        const UInt32 CS_HREDRAW = 2;
        const UInt32 COLOR_WINDOW = 5;
        const UInt32 COLOR_BACKGROUND = 1;
        const UInt32 IDC_CROSS = 32515;
        const UInt32 WM_DESTROY = 2;
        const UInt32 WM_PAINT = 0x0f;
        const UInt32 WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        const UInt32 WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        struct WNDCLASSEX
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int cbSize;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int style;
            public IntPtr lpfnWndProc; 
            public int cbClsExtra;
            public int cbWndExtra;
            public IntPtr hInstance;
            public IntPtr hIcon;
            public IntPtr hCursor;
            public IntPtr hbrBackground;
            public string lpszMenuName;
            public string lpszClassName;
            public IntPtr hIconSm;
        }


        private WndProc delegWndProc = myWndProc;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UpdateWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CreateWindowEx")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(
           int dwExStyle,
           UInt16 regResult,
           //string lpClassName,
           string lpWindowName,
           UInt32 dwStyle,
           int x,
           int y,
           int nWidth,
           int nHeight,
           IntPtr hWndParent,
           IntPtr hMenu,
           IntPtr hInstance,
           IntPtr lpParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "RegisterClassEx")]
        static extern System.UInt16 RegisterClassEx([In] ref WNDCLASSEX lpWndClass);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetLastError();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void PostQuitMessage(int nExitCode);

        //[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        //static extern sbyte GetMessage(out MSG lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin,
        //   uint wMsgFilterMax);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, int lpCursorName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool TranslateMessage([In] ref MSG lpMsg);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage([In] ref MSG lpmsg);    


        internal bool create()
        {
            WNDCLASSEX wind_class = new WNDCLASSEX();
            wind_class.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WNDCLASSEX));
            wind_class.style = (int)(CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS ) ; //Doubleclicks are active
            wind_class.hbrBackground = (IntPtr) COLOR_BACKGROUND  +1 ; //Black background, +1 is necessary
            wind_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
            wind_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
            wind_class.hInstance = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(this.GetType().Module); ;// alternative: Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
            wind_class.hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
            wind_class.hCursor = LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)IDC_CROSS);// Crosshair cursor;
            wind_class.lpszMenuName = null;
            wind_class.lpszClassName = "myClass";
            wind_class.lpfnWndProc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(delegWndProc);
            wind_class.hIconSm = IntPtr.Zero;
            ushort regResult = RegisterClassEx(ref wind_class);

            if (regResult == 0)
            {
                uint error = GetLastError();
                return false;
            }
            string wndClass = wind_class.lpszClassName;

            //The next line did NOT work with me! When searching the web, the reason seems to be unclear! 
            //It resulted in a zero hWnd, but GetLastError resulted in zero (i.e. no error) as well !!??)
            //IntPtr hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wind_class.lpszClassName, "MyWnd", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 30, 40, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, wind_class.hInstance, IntPtr.Zero);

            //This version worked and resulted in a non-zero hWnd
            IntPtr hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, regResult, "Hello Win32", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 300, 400, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, wind_class.hInstance, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (hWnd == ((IntPtr)0))
            {
                uint error = GetLastError();
                return false;
            }
            ShowWindow(hWnd, 1);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            return true;

            //The explicit message pump is not necessary, messages are obviously dispatched by the framework.
            //However, if the while loop is implemented, the functions are called... Windows mysteries...
            //MSG msg;
            //while (GetMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0) != 0)
            //{
            //    TranslateMessage(ref msg);
            //    DispatchMessage(ref msg);
            //}
        }

        private static IntPtr myWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            switch (msg)
            {
                // All GUI painting must be done here
                case WM_PAINT:
                    break;

                case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK :
                    MessageBox.Show("Doubleclick");
                    break;

                case WM_DESTROY:
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);

                    //If you want to shutdown the application, call the next function instead of DestroyWindow
                    //PostQuitMessage(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @josh but when i Close the Child window, The Program cant register that again. why ? could you explain that for me !?

Comment: The registering procedure is - for a certain window class (not to be confused with the C# class - usually done only once. Once registered, that class cannot registered a second time. As a result, you should store the regResult variable and the wind_class structure as member variables. To get a second window, just call the CreateWindowEx function with the regResult of the first registration, and you will get as many windows as you want.

Comment: You're much better off making the WndProc non-static. Just use wind_class.lpfnWndProc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new WndProc(myWndProc)) and make myWndProc non-static. Then you don't have to go nuts trying to get the class instance inside the wndproc.

Comment: The "Windows mystery" is due to the fact that Windows only dispatches messages to requests made in the thread that created them.  As such, if you are going to run the message pump in your code you'll need to create a thread that examines an incoming structure in a queue.  It's populated in the current thread, but in the loop in the message thread it examines and sees a new request.  It will then register the class and create the window and begin dispatching messages to it from itself.  Gotta love Windows. :-)

Answer (score 10):

The problem is the marshaling of strings to LPStr, if you do it like this then the class name works:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    struct WNDCLASSEX
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int cbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int style;
        public IntPtr lpfnWndProc;
        public int cbClsExtra;
        public int cbWndExtra;
        public IntPtr hInstance;
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public IntPtr hCursor;
        public IntPtr hbrBackground;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string lpszMenuName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string lpszClassName;
        public IntPtr hIconSm;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CreateWindowEx")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(
       int dwExStyle,
       //UInt16 regResult,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
       string lpClassName,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
       string lpWindowName,
       UInt32 dwStyle,
       int x,
       int y,
       int nWidth,
       int nHeight,
       IntPtr hWndParent,
       IntPtr hMenu,
       IntPtr hInstance,
       IntPtr lpParam);
```

Comment: This is the actual correct answer. With this example, the class name was created correctly.